# FOSOAuthServerBundle with multiple user providers

Tags: symfony, multiple-tables, fosoauthserverbundle

I have several Entities implementing UserInterface on a project (applications and their users) but seems FOSOAuthServerBundle can be instantiated with only user_provider, but I need to have opportunity to extract from token different Entities of a UserInterface. Is any way to perform it?